# Watching data in Hive database with RxDart

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, hivedb

I’m using Hive and RxDart
Is there a better way of emitting values from my Hive box than

```
  Stream<List<Tissue>> watchTissues() {
    return tissueBox
        .watch()
        .map((event) => getTissues())
        .startWith(getTissues());
  }  

  List<Tissue> getTissues() {
    return List<Tissue>.from(tissueBox.values);
  }
```

It works but looks too verbose to me, so wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: This is not verbose. If anything, it's too concise and could benefit from some documentation.